# Django move models classmethod to another file

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have model

```
Order(models.Model):
  name = models.Charfield()
  
  @classmethod 
  do_something(cls):
    print('do soemthing')
```

What I want to do is to move `do_something` method from my model to another file.I want to do it because I have several other big methods in this model and want to structure the code, don't like lengh of this file. It's getting big > 700 lines of code.

So I want to move my method to another file and import it, so it still can  be used like modelmethod

like this:

`Order.do_something()`

Any ideas?

Comment: Try creating a new class with `do_something` method and inherit it in `Order` class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How can I separate functions of class into multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561840/python-how-can-i-separate-functions-of-class-into-multiple-files)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**inheritance** -- (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming))

```
# some_package/some_module.py

class MyFooKlass:
    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls):
        # do something
        return 'foo'

# my_app/models.py

from some_package.some_module import MyFooKlass

class Order(models.Model, MyFooKlass):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Comment: I will check it