# Python Split Class to multiple files when access parent via decorator

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this Discord.py `Cog` object that contains a bunch of methods that I would like to split into multiple files to browse easier. (most stuff cut out for brevity)

```
class VoteManager(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.group(pass_context=True, invoke_without_command=True)
    async def vote(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'Command not found.  Use `{BOT_CALL_PREFIX}vote help` for commands.')

    def new(self, channel_id):
        pass  # Actual logic for new_command, separated so it could be called without context

    @vote.command(name='new')
    async def new_command(self):
        pass  # Really long function, etc.
```

What I want is to be able to split definitions like `new` and `new_command` into their own file `new.py`.

The `VoteManager` class is in the `__init__.py` file of `discordbot.voting` module.  So when used, I use `bot.add_cog(discordbot.voting.VoteManager(bot))` to add it to the registry of commands for the bot.

The goal is to be able to just do something like `from .voting.new import *` in the `VoteManager` class and have it read the functions to be added.

Comment: You could define pure function in separate files and call them from your class file by just passing the arguments and potentially the self. Or you actually compose multiple classes which feels maybe more clean.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561840/python-how-can-i-separate-functions-of-class-into-multiple-files) help you?