# Python: separate utilities file or use static methods?

Tags: python, oop, functional-programming, namespaces, static-methods

In python I have getters and setters, and calculate utilities. The getters return the property, the setters set the property and the calculate utilities are functions that calculate stuff with the arguments. E.g.

`obj.property = calculate_property(arguments)`

However, there are various ways to implement `calculate_property`, it could

1. be a part of the class `calculate_property(self)` and return `_property`
2. It could be an independent function which could be moved to a separate file
3. It could be a static method

My problem with 1) is that the arguments to calculate_property can be obscured because they might be contained within the object itself, and it is not possible to use the function outside of the object. In both 2 and 3 the functional form of `calculate` is retained but the namespaces are different.

So I'm ruling out 1) for this reason.

IIf I go with 2) the advantage is that I can split all my utilities up into small files e.g. utilities_a.py, utilities_b.py and import them as modules.

If I go with 3) the functions remain in the same file making it overall longer, but the functions are encapsulated better.

Which is preferred between 2) and 3)? Or am I missing a different solution?

Comment: `1` is not possible because you've already stated the data is rather buried; meanwhile I would pick `3` over `2` because it does seem very intimate to your class (it creates its properties) and would serve as helper.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47562412/2359945) of achieving both `2` and `3`.  Just remember to add `self` into the signature as is mentioned, and you can place your class methods and static methods in another file then import only as you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve both `2` and `3` with this example of adding a static method to your class that is defined in a separate file.

`helper.py`:

```
def square(self):
    self.x *= self.x
```

`fitter.py`:

```
class Fitter(object):
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x
    from helper import square

if name == '__main__':
    f = Fitter(9)
    f.square()
    print(f.x)
```

Output:

```
81
```

Adapted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47562412/2359945) which was doing this for a class method.  Seems to work for static method, too.

Comment: Wow, that's really cool! Importing inside the class definition adds it to the class namespace. This is what I liked about static methods and keeping the files separate. However, I agree with your comment above strategy 3 is probably the most clear despite the length of the files becoming long.

Comment: @Cody I thought it was cool too :)  If you found this answer useful, please consider accepting it.  Thank you.

Comment: @CodyAldaz I've already used imports in functions and maybe in classes. (E.g. pdb.set_trace()). Never realized that import set the object into that namespace. Good to know. Thanks.