# Call Tkinter GUI Frame Class on Different Files

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, frame, file-handling

I'm trying to build a frontend for an app.

I have `main.py` with my tkinter window class.

Now, using frames, I added a top, left, and middle frame.

- Top - Banner
- Left - Navbar
- Middle - working area

The middle frame shows different frames, depending on which button is clicked on the navbar.
I want to move those frames to their own file, as they will become quite long, considering all the info they have to show.

Currently, my `main.py` looks like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.top()
        self.left()
        self.middle()
        self.pageOne()

    def top(self):
        self.top_panel = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.top_panel.pack()

        self.logo = tk.Label(self.top_panel, text="LOGO GOES HERE", fg="Blue", width=40)
        self.logo.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def left(self):
        self.left_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.left_frame.pack(side="left", fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)

        self.page_one = tk.Button(self.left_frame, text="Page 1", command=self.pageOne)
        self.page_one.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.page_two = tk.Button(self.left_frame, text="Page 2", command=self.pageTwo)
        self.page_two.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.page_three = tk.Button(self.left_frame, text="Page 3", command=self.pageThree)
        self.page_three.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)


    # Middle frame, working area
    def middle(self):
        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="red", width=60)
        self.right_frame.pack(side="left", fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    # Frames to open on middle frame
    def pageOne(self):
        self.page_one_frame = tk.Frame(self.right_frame, bg="yellow")
        try:
            self.page_two_frame.destroy() or self.page_three_frame.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            self.page_one_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        else:
            self.page_one_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        # pageOne Contents
        self.label = tk.Label(self.page_one_frame, text="This is page one")
        self.label.pack()

    def pageTwo(self):
        self.page_two_frame = tk.Frame(self.right_frame, bg="blue")
        try:
            self.page_one_frame.destroy() or self.page_three_frame.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            self.page_two_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        else:
            self.page_two_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        # pageTwo contents Contents
        self.label = tk.Label(self.page_two_frame, text="This is page two")
        self.label.pack()

    def pageThree(self):
        self.page_three_frame = tk.Frame(self.right_frame, bg="green")
        try:
            self.page_one_frame.destroy() or self.page_two_frame.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            self.page_three_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        else:
            self.page_three_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        # pageThree contents Contents
        self.label = tk.Label(self.page_three_frame, text="This is page three")
        self.label.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What would be the correct way of "moving" those `pageOne`, `pageTwo`, `pageThree` methods to their own files, and calling them with the button commands?

Comment: The essence of your question is [How can I separate functions of class into multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561840/how-can-i-separate-functions-of-class-into-multiple-files) — the fact that the methods are called by clicking on tkinter `Button`s is irrelevant.

Comment: I just tested this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47562412/355230) to the duplicate question and it worked. Basically I just copied and pasted the code of each of the three methods into separate files. Un-indented it one level, and added an `import tkinter as tk` to beginning of each.